# How to prove $\forall x:P(x) \implies \exists x:P(x)$ without using UI?

Tags: logic

In standard FOL, can we prove $\forall x: P(x) \implies \exists x:P(x)$ *without* introducing a new free variable by universal instantiation, i.e without using $\forall x: P(x) \vdash P(y)$ where $y$ is not does not occur in $P(x)$?

I have tried direct proof, proof by contradiction, and proof by contrapositive. It looks impossible to me, but can't prove it.

Comment: I am not quite sure what your concern is. Universal instantiation has no side-conditions, so you could use $x$ rather than $y$.  I can't say for certain, because I don't know exactly what formulation of FOL you are using, but I would be very surprised if (a) you have a rule of universal instantiation and (b) you can prove  this formula without using it. (If you can, then there is some redundancy in your set of rules.)

Comment: Not everyone agrees that $\exists x:\top$ is a theorem of first-order logic (i.e., that we only consider inhabited structures).  IIRC, Poizat's book on model theory has a rant about this (he takes the point of view that the empty structure should not be excluded).  In this case, $\forall x:\top$ does not imply $\exists x:\top$ because the former is tautological but the latter need not be true.

Comment: PS: When I said "universal instantiation has no side-condition" that 's because I adopt the convention that $P[t/x]$ means $P$ with $t$ substituted for $x$ and *with bound variables renamed as necessary to avoid variable capture problems*". Other don't adopt this convention and have a side-condition on this rule. Like I said, you need to say exactly how you are formulating FOL in this kind of question.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen Do you have a reference for an at least first-order-logic that doesn't assume a nonempty universe?  I'd be very interested in reading an exhibition that doesn't require such an annoying assumption.

Comment: @DanielV Have a look at my proof-checking freeware available at my website http://www.dcproof.com The system of logic that it is based on does not assume a non-empty universe. In this and other ways, it is less philosophical and more mathematical and practical than standard FOL, if that makes sense.

Comment: @DanChristensen I actually have downloaded your software and visited your website, but haven't found any documentation for your logic.  Maybe I'll look again, but any chance I could get some help with that?

Comment: @DanChristensen A two or three page document that says "this is the grammar, these are the axioms, these are the rules of inferences" would be really helpful.

Comment: @DanielV Click the Help** button in upper-right corner of the main screen. Then click on User Reference Guide. Then you will see the headings for Notation and Rules of Inference. The Notation section will spell out the syntax and grammar under various headings.

Comment: @DanielV As I mentioned, Poizat's *Course in Model Theory* does not make the nonemptiness assumption (see his comment on "almost equivalent" formulæ at the end of §2.1, p. 22), but it's true he doesn't consider proof theory much, so the slight annoyance of making proofs work over the empty universe doesn't bother him. (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) The annoyance is naturally resolved when working in higher-order logic, where a variably of any type being introduced counts as an assumption (essentially, "the type is inhabited"). This is how proof-checkers generally work. If you really want first-order logic, the simplest way to do things is probably to introduce a special atomic formula "U" meaning "the universe is inhabited", which can be deduced from any existential formula or from any (formula involving a) closed term, and is required as a hypothesis for existential introduction.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the following system from *A Primer for Logic and Proof*, Holly P. Hirst and Jeffry L. Hirst,

> Axioms 
>   Axiom 1: $A \implies (B \implies A)$ 
>   Axiom 2: $(A \implies (B \implies C)) \implies ((A \implies B) \implies (A \implies C))$ 
>   Axiom 3: $(\lnot B \implies \lnot A) \implies ((\lnot B \implies A) \implies B)$ 
>   Axiom 4: $(\forall x ~:~  A(x)) \implies A(t)$, provided that $t$ is free for $x$ in $A(x)$. 
>   Axiom 5: $\forall x ~:~ (A \implies B) \implies (A \implies \forall x ~:~ B)$, provided that $x$ does not occur free
>   in $A$. 
>    
>   Rules of inference 
>   Modus Ponens (MP): From $A$ and $A \implies B$, deduce $B$. 
>   Generalization (GEN):  From $A$, deduce $\forall x ~:~ A$.

Notice that axiom 4 is the only axiom that doesn't hold in an empty universe (substitute false for A).  Also notice the theorem to prove doesn't hold in an empty universe.  So this axiom must be used somewhere in the proof.  So a new variable must be introduced if you use these axioms.

Comment: Ah, I was under the impression that he didn't want any new free variable, whether it was named $x$ or not.  Is Enderton public domain?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA $x$ is not free variable in Axiom 4. It is a bound variable. The $t$ would be a free variable.